# Nginx redirect certain location to separate server

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to separate our application server from our website gallery storage.
I have an application server on xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and gallery server with all the images on xxx.xxx.xxx.2 . Now I want to make it so every time request comes into server with the ending of *.jpeg and/or beginning of www.domain.com/uploads, would get redirected to www.gallerydomain.com.

I have checked a second server and it is working perfectly fine.

Now the on the 1st server i tried doing :

```
location /uploads {
        proxy_pass      http://www.gallerydomain.com;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any1 has any experience with this kind of situation in Nginx ? Or could some1 point me to the right direction ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the client, or do you want to transparently proxy their request?

Comment: I want to redirect a client. Well the idea is that while client is browsing, the picture requests comes from different domain. Also id user is uploading pictures it uploads it to that domain.

Comment: Is it basis of a load balancing I an talking about ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I did not see your comment above. To make redirections on client-side this can be useful :

```
server {

    server_name    domain.com;

    ...

    rewrite ^/uploads/(.*)$      http://www.gallerydomain.com/$1        permanent;
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.jpg$         http://www.gallerydomain.com/$1.jpg    permanent;

    ...

}
```

Nginx returns an 'HTTP 301 Moved permanently' response on every request that matches a rewrite pattern. This way the browser redirects to the new location (and is aware of), according to the content of the 'Location:' HTTP response header.

Comment: Cheers, I will test it out maybe this weekend, will give you heads up when I get results

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by using a regular expression in the location block :

```
location ~ ^/uploads/|\.jpg$ {
    proxy_pass http://www.gallerydomain.com;
}
```